# Automated check-in using tf.exe fails with TFS policy failure

Tags: xaml, tfs, build

We have incorporated an automatic check-in from a TFS build that is throwing an error with regards to a policy failure, even though the check-in does get committed.

The command we are using is as follows;

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe checkin FileSpec1.*.* FileSpec2.*.* /bypass /override:"Check-in from automated build" /comment:"Check-in from automated build D-BuildName-M_20141013.6

The error that we are getting in the TFS build log is;

Handle Error from TF
TF10139: The following check-in policies have not been satisfied:
Inputs 
Condition: True 
You must associate this check-in with one or more work items.

However, from the documentation that I can find, setting the /override flag should stop this from ocurring.

[Checkin Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c327ca1z.aspx)

The file do get checked in, but the build is a partial success due to this error.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on 2013, just living with it at the moment

Comment: The build making changes and checking them in is not recommended behavior. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MrHinsh We have an automated build that compiles shared components  that need to be re-versioned and built against each other periodically and then checked into  a central location.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are checking in? All your binary dependencies should be handled with NuGet and not checked into source.

Comment: @MrHinsh For the sake of brevity, let's just say it is not possible to use anything but TFS in this particular environment, so I am left with finding a solution to this particular problem.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. I'm using PowerShell to execute tf.exe. As for those of you who are questioning why we're doing this with binaries, you know nothing of our environment. Suffice to say, we need to check in. When I did this with MSBuild, it works fine, without throwing the exception back to the build. From PowerShell, it's throwing an exception, then getting overridden, and the files are checked in successfully. However, the build is a partial success, which is not a good thing. I'm hoping there's a way to eat that exception in PowerShell and get past this. That search led here.